# dojo.xhrGet not being able to call WCF GET method returning DbContext object with WCF support

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, dojo, dbcontext

So here's the deal:

I have an operation contract for a method defined this way:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

aspnet_Users GetUsers();
```

When I test the method in a WCF Test client I get the results fine, but when I send a `dojo` GET request, I get an error

> 504: "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes. "

Neither of the solutions from previous similar problems helped in this case. Here's the dojo call and the web config:

```
var request = dojo.xhrGet({
    url: 'http://localhost/Authentication/Service1.svc/GetUsers',
    handleAs: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    load: doSomething,
    error: OnError
});

 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyAppServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="web">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
          <bufferedReceive maxPendingMessagesPerChannel="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="214748364777777" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="214748364777777" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfAuthenticationService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfAuthenticationService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="data source=serv;initial catalog=aspnetdb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="aspnetdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModelFirst.UsersModel.csdl|res://*/DataModelFirst.UsersModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModelFirst.UsersModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=serv;initial catalog=aspnetdb;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The method returns DbContext entity with WCF support.

I have another method that returns okay results with `dojo` post method call, so my guess is it's something to do with the `DbContext`... I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: The server returned 504 http code which corresponds to timeout, so probably the backend call took too much time - maybe the db query is not optimized or the returned data is too big?

Comment: @Petrushev: I tested it when the query should return one record only (and the table contains three records :) ); does that still look to you as a timeout?

Comment: ... one more thing (important): I have another method that returns the string of the result record (actually only part of it, but still the dbcontext returns my record), so the problem is when I want the method to return the ado.net object from DB (instead of the string)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was "'aspnet_Users' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type."